# Styling the application with android/style

Tags: android-activity, themes, android-manifest, android-support-library, android-styles

I am trying to style my app using android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" however I keep getting an error at runtime:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ghanghan.myapplication/com.example.ghanghan.myapplicat‌​ion.MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

I later discovered that anytime I use @android:style/ I get the same error.

Is there sone library I need to import?

Note: Also my minimum SDK is set to 19.

Comment: can you provide the error ?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ghanghan.myapplication/com.example.ghanghan.myapplication.MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: btw I am following this tutorial http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: The AppCompatActivity requires an Theme.AppCompat

Comment: I realized what i was doing wrong, I extended the Activity class instead of ActionBarActivity, and took out the support libraries. I'm still new to Android app development so I didn't really understand the problem aha